Substitute values in a SELECT with other data from the same table only under specific conditions
I've got a set a of data that is basically this:



JobRow
Hours
Date
JobID
OriginalJobRow




101
4
2001-06-13
21777A
Null


269
12
2004-11-30
24999A
101


270
10
2006-06-02
26888A
Null



I'd like to find a way to select all information from my table, replacing JobID values where OriginalJobRow isn't null with the JobID from the JobRow column that's equal to the OriginalJobRow's value, just for the purposes of the SELECT query.
In this example, I'd like my SELECT to return 21777A as the JobID for JobRow 269, since OriginalJobRow isn't null on that row.
How might I accomplish this in a SELECT query?

Can there be a chain of more than one job to follow? e.g. could another row have an OriginalJobRow of 269 in this example?

@MartinSmith Yes, there are multiple rows that have the same OriginalJobRow.

That wasn't the question. The question was whether you needed to navigate a chain of such linkages, e.g. if row X is pointing to 269 and then 269 is pointing to 101 then going up one level in the chain X -> 269 -> 101 doesn't get the root original job row. i.e. does this need to be done recursively?

Oh! I see what you mean. No, I've no need for this to be recursive.

A self join can be used to find the JobID related to OriginalJobRow. If there are multiple rows with JobRow=101 then JobRow 269 would be repeated for each match.
SELECT e1.JobRow, e1.Hours, e1.Date, ISNULL(e2.JobID,e1.JobID) as JobID
FROM Example e1
LEFT JOIN Example e2 on e2.JobRow=e1.OriginalJobRow

fiddle



JobRow
Hours
Date
JobID




101
4
2001-06-13
21777A


269
12
2004-11-30
21777A


270
10
2006-06-02
26888A



You could also use a sub query. If there are multiple rows with JobRow=101 then JobRow 269 would be NOT be repeated for each match. It would use only the top 1 value. Add ORDER BY to make the results predictable.
SELECT e1.JobRow, e1.Hours, e1.Date, 
ISNULL((SELECT  TOP 1 JobID FROM Example WHERE JobRow=e1.OriginalJobRow),e1.JobID) as JobID
FROM Example e1

fiddle with duplicates

For the clarification that no recursion is needed then yeah a simple self  join seems the best approach. No need to have all the baggage of windowed aggregates and spools

An alternative to self-join is to use window function:ed MAX to get the value per "JobID/OriginalID", something like:
SELECT  *
INTO #data
FROM    (
    VALUES  (101, 4, N'2001-06-13', N'21777A', NULL)
    ,   (269, 12, N'2004-11-30', N'24999A', 101)
    ,   (270, 10, N'2006-06-02', N'26888A', NULL)
) t (JobRow,Hours,Date,JobID,OriginalJobRow)

SELECT  MAX(case when OriginalJobRow is null then JobId end) OVER(PARTITION BY ISNULL(OriginalJobRow, JobRow)) AS JobIDNew
,   *
FROM    #data

A little wrinkle is that we need to prioritize the row where original jobRow is NULL.
Output:



JobIDNew
JobRow
Hours
Date
JobID
OriginalJobRow




21777A
101
4
2001-06-13
21777A
NULL


21777A
269
12
2004-11-30
24999A
101


26888A
270
10
2006-06-02
26888A
NULL



